# How should I bundle pandoc with my OpenShift application?

Tags: bash, openshift, jekyll, pandoc, openshift-cartridge

I've been running jekyll on OpenShift using https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/jekyll-openshift. I want to be able to rebuild my web site automatically in order to future-date posts and not have to rebuild/reupload in order to publish them. This means that I have a cron job running on OpenShift that rebuilds my jekyll site, adapting the `deploy` bash script from the OpenShift cartridge I am using. So far, so good.

Now I want to use `pandoc` in place of `kramdown`. Now I have a problem. How do I install `pandoc` as part of my application's deployment to OpenShift?

I've searched the web for an hour or so. I'm getting conflicting reports. Use puppet. Build from source, which starts with "Install the Haskell platform". I don't mind the work, but I'd like some idea which path to go down before doing down them all and tearing my hair out.

So... which path would you choose and which articles can I read to guide me through learning what I need to learn in order to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I built pandoc from source on my target operating system, which was CentOS 6.7. I bundled this with my application in $APP/libs. I changed the OpenShift action hook script to add $APP/libs to the PATH. Everything now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc is written in Haskell, so you'll have to build it using `cabal` or `stack`. However once built, you can move the binary to your server:

From [Installing Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html#creating-a-relocatable-binary):

> It is possible to compile pandoc such that the data files pandoc uses are embedded in the binary. (The executables in the binary are built this way.) The resulting binary can be run from any directory and is completely self-contained.

```
cabal update
cabal install hsb2hs
cabal install --flags="embed_data_files" pandoc pandoc-citeproc
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears that I have built pandoc correctly, but I can't run it on OpenShift. I get "cannot execute binary file". Now I guess I need to get some help on OpenShift in particular to find out what's happening.

Comment: Maybe try building it on the exact same version of the OS (also 32 vs 64 bit) as you've running on OpenShift.

Comment: Yes; I think I have 64-bit, but not the exact OS. Virtualbox, here I come.... Thanks.

Comment: It took way too long to get it to work, but it worked. Thank you, @mb21.